# Is there a real difference between the voltages produced at the negative and positive ranges of the AC sine wave?

Tags: ac, sine, negative

This a general electrical question. When reviewing the AC sin wave, we note that the curvature of the wave fluctuates between a positive and negative 180 degree range. Is there a real difference between the voltages produced at the negative and positive ranges of the AC sine wave? Or does the negative or positive designations of the AC sine wave just mark a point in time in which the loop disrupted the northern and southern magnets of the induction motor? I would lean toward the marking a "point in time" explanation, yet it is my understanding that the diodes used in a bridge rectifier (to convert AC to DC) are designed to specifically absorb either 'positively' or  'negatively' charged voltage, depending on the type of diode. If this is the case, then it suggests that the negative and positive AC voltages produced from an magnetic indication do have different qualities. Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Brian Ghilliotti

Comment: Diodes don't "absorb" voltage.  They pass current depending on the voltage difference between the anode and cathode

Comment: Voltage is a quantity measured between two points, and it very definitely has a sign. Other than that I think this question is confused?

Comment: You want to know if the positive semi-sinusoid and the negative semi-sinusoid are identical or if they differ in amplitude and or shape due to some technicalities of the generator used to produce it? And that doubt arises from the fact that you heard that there are diodes for positive voltages, and diodes for negative voltages? Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking, but generators like those used to power the electric grid inherently put out AC sine waves.  The shape of the positive and negative parts are identical, except for polarity.

None of this has antyhing to do with full wave bridges.  Those are used to effectively take the absolute value of the incoming voltage - minus a little drop due to the diodes not being perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: There is no real difference between the +ve or -ve portion of a voltage or current waveform.  It's not the direction of the voltage or current, but how they are used.

Voltage reverses 60 times a second for 60Hz.  Applied to a light, the light goes on and off 120 times a second.

That does not mean, we do not take advantage positive and negative portions of the waveform.  Half-wave rectifiers clip +ve or -ve for applications.  Full-wave bridge rectifiers convert ac into +ve or -ve humpy dc for power supplies.

[image: Half-wave rectifiers]

Three-phase voltages create a revolving magnetic field for induction motors.

[image: Three-phase rotating magnetic field]

So most of your question has misconceptions.  Typically, AC voltage is created by synchronous generators, not induction motors.  An induction motor has non-salient poles which are not easily discernible and switch between N-S and S-N as magnetic field rotates.  Diodes pass voltages when forward biased and stop when reverse biased used in power supplies and many other applications.